# Escaping dollar sign and curly brace in bash

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

I'm making a script that needs to write ${somestring} to a file.
The way I figured doing this was by escaping the dollar sign, but when it executes, the string ends up empty.

Is there a way to escape this correctly?

My code:

```
# \$\{somestring\} works, but leaves the \'s which I don't want.
myvar=("Yes I require multiple lines.
    Test \${somestring} test"); 

echo "$myvar" >> "mytest.conf";
```

Comment: Also, don't use the parentheses if you don't want an array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use single quotes, so that `${}` won't be interpreted:

```
$ myvar=5
$ echo 'this is ${myvar}'
this is ${myvar}
$ echo "this is ${myvar}"
this is 5
```

---

Note, though, that your approach is working (at least to me on Bash):

```
$ myvar=("Yes I require multiple lines.
  test \${somestring} test");
$ echo "$myvar" > a
$ cat a
Yes I require multiple lines.
  test ${somestring} test
```

Comment: This example probably works, but the entire script is 400 lines of code which makes it less easy to post on stackoverflow. Anyways this worked! Thanks, i'll accept in 4 mins

Comment: Nice to read that! By the way, I think with these +4 I just got the gold badge for shell. This is an exciting moment... hello mum! :)